# Reading command line argument on push in github action

Tags: node.js, github-actions

I have a workflow which is executed on push. Is there any way to read some flags from the push command? So, I will push like this on my local computer

```
git push origin my-branch --do-something
```

I want to pass the flag (if available) `--do-something` as it is into my Action like

```
...
      - name: Custom cmd
        run: yarn my:script:cmd --do-something # its passed here
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid it's not possible like this.

Depending on what you exactly need to trigger and how complicated things you want to pass, the most common solutions are:

1. Trigger workflows based on `tags` and encode options into tags themselves - so for example to identify if workflow should make public or internal build, by having the proper format of tag.
2. Pass information in message commit. You can encode the command as [-do-something] in GIT message and then parse it inside the workflow.

   For example:

   ```
   if: contains(github.event.commits[0].message, '[run_test_workflow]')
   ```
3. Use dispatch_workflow event in GitHub to directly trigger desired workflow with all possible inputs - probably most flexible - could be integrated with post-commit hooks.